# No me carga los archivos css por el .htcss

Tags: php, css, mvc, apache, .htaccess

Lo que pasa es que ando haciendo el proyecto de un curso utilizando php con MVC.
Como puede ver lo inicio desde la carpeta public

En la carpeta public el index lo que hace es hacer el routing para las rutas porque las paginas lo tengo en la carpeta views

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la carpeta build tengo los archivos en cada carpeta, en este caso el css se llama app.css
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pasa es que con el codigo que pude conseguir en el .htacces solo logra redireccionar a las rutas con el REQUEST_URI para que no me marque el 404

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Este codigo me sirve para ir a las rutas sin que muestre el archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así tengo configurado mi archivo index.php en la carpeta public

```
<?php 

require_once __DIR__ . '/../includes/app.php';

use Controllers\LoginController;
use MVC\Router;

$router = new Router();

// Iniciar Sesión
$router->get('/', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
$router->post('/', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
$router->get('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout']);

// Recuperar Password
$router->get('/olvide', [LoginController::class, 'olvide']);
$router->post('/olvide', [LoginController::class, 'olvide']);
$router->get('/recuperar', [LoginController::class, 'recuperar']);
$router->post('/recuperar', [LoginController::class, 'recuperar']);

// Crear cuenta
$router->get('/crear-cuenta', [LoginController::class, 'crear']);
$router->post('/crear-cuenta', [LoginController::class, 'crear']);

// Comprueba y valida las rutas, que existan y les asigna las funciones del Controlador
$router->comprobarRutas();

?>
```

En el inicio de la raiz del proyecto, tengo un archivo llamado Router.php con un metodo (funcion en POO) que funciona así

```
public function comprobarRutas()
    {

        $urlActual = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?? '/';
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        if ($method === 'GET') {
            $urlActual = explode('?',$urlActual)[0];
            $fn = $this->getRoutes[$urlActual] ?? null;
        } else {
            $urlActual = explode('?',$urlActual)[0];
            $fn = $this->postRoutes[$urlActual] ?? null;
        }


        if ( $fn ) {
            // Call user fn va a llamar una función cuando no sabemos cual sera
            call_user_func($fn, $this); // This es para pasar argumentos
        } else {
            echo "Página No Encontrada o Ruta no válida";
        }
    }
```

Lo que pasa es que con el codigo que mostré del .htaccess me manda ese error al querer buscar el css (igual me pasaria si quisiera cargar otros archivos como los js, imagenes, etc), como pueden ver me manda el `echo "Página No Encontrada o Ruta no válida"` **Ignoren lo de video downloader, fonts y lo que muestren debajo, siempre me aparecen en cualquier pagina**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Lo que pasa es que no se como se tendria que configurar el archivo .htaccess para que no muestren las paginas así sin estilos, es decir, que si me carguen los archivos css, js, img, etc y que al poner una ruta como dominio.com/ruta-ejemplo (que no muestra el archivo ni extension .php) me funcionen correctamente**

PD: Lo hago con Apache 2.4, mi proyecto lo tengo en htdocs

Answer (score 0):

todo proyecto MVC se maneja asi:
las carpetas de codigo (build) estan ocultas a la raiz, pues la raiz es la que esta en modo publico.
debes hacer esto:

`

```
 projecto
├build
|├vistas
|└controladores
└htdocs
 ├css
 ├img
 └js
```

de esta forma todo el código esta resguardado y podrás mantener el css y el js sin problemas.
ahora bien si te es necesario tener el css y js en build puedes usar links simbolicos

el .htaccess puede ser:

1

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule . /..build/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

o

2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

en el 2 se mantiene pero el index.php

`include('../build/index.php')`